# Get git repository from shared host bluehost

Tags: git, repository, shared-hosting

I have shared host with git installed on it, I make repository on some      directory and make some changes to files and make commit.
Now I need to get back changes to the local version on my computer.

The problem is I can't get repository path with the remote command.

I used:

```
git init
```

to create repository.

Command:

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

returns blank

And I can't use:

```
git clone
```

the path is wrong.

And this is my config file on life host

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
```

What command should I use to clone the remote Bluehost repo on my local workstation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have [enabled ssh access to your Bluehost server](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/180), the git clone command would be (see [ssh connection](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/301)):

```
git clone username@yourserver:path/to/repo.git
```

Replace:

- `username` by your username on Bluehost,
- `yourserver` by the Bluehost server fqn (fully qualified name)
- `path/to/repo.git` the relative path of the repo under your home: `/home/username/path/to/repo.git`

Comment: i use bitvise ssh to connect to server and i cant find where is repo.git file i looked in .git dir no thing with .git extension

Comment: ok well that what happens when i log from git bash with you instruction this  is replay

     does not appear to be a git repository
i am navigate to my project in the path where i can fount the repo.git file

Comment: @Roufail then you need to ssh to your server, and in /home/username you create a bare repo: `git init --bare myrepo.git`. Then in your local repo, you can `git remote add origin username@yourserver:/home/username/myrepo.git`, and `git push -u origin master`

Comment: @Roufail Great! Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote and http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer